# Concatenate two integer to get a float in Java

Tags: java, int, concatenation

I have two integer values as below

```
int fb = (int) (duration.toMinutes() / 60.0);
    int fb1 = (int) (duration.toMinutes() % 60.0);
```

I want a float variable like below

```
float fb2 = fb.fb1
```

Example :If I have two int values as fb = 3 and fb1=30 i need float fb2= 3.30

Help me how to achieve the above in java with minimal code.

Comment: In your example, `fb1` being 1 or 10 would give the same value for `fb2`. Is this intentional?

Comment: Minimal code: `Float.parseFloat(fb + "." + fb1)` (assuming that's what you want - cf comment above)...

Comment: `float fb2 = fb + fb1 / 100f`;

Comment: @saka1029 That won't work for integers with more than 2 digits.

Comment: @assylias Almost all the answers below just copied your comment, lol

Comment: `float fb2 = (float)(fb + fb1/100.0)`;

Comment: Which do you want `3.3` or `3.03` when `fb = 3` and `fb1 = 3`?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès, well that´s a pretty trivial question, due to this the answers might aswell not be that different from the comment.

Comment: @DimaSan they did without mentioning the important caveat that it probably isn't what the op wants. fb1=1 and fb1=10 give the same result - that's probably not the idea...

Comment: @assylias sure you are right, but I'm sure for many cases this short elegant solution will work.

Comment: Sorry, but for me the question may technically make sense, but are you really sure that representing a time 3h30 (210 min) as float does make any sense ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Float.parseFloat()`, like this:

```
float fb2 = Float.parseFloat(fb + "." + fb1);
```

You could also use `Float.valueOf()` combined with `String.valueOf()`, like this:

```
float fb2 = java.lang.Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(fb) +"."+ 
String.valueOf(fb1));
```

Comment: assylias's comment rules!

Comment: How to have two decimal precision in the appraoch above

Comment: It does have 2 decimal precision, see [here](http://ideone.com/TvNKvm) @user3669712

Comment: @ArnavBorborah I think the comment is about the fact that (fb=1,fb1=10) -> fb2=1.1 and (fb=1,fb1=1) -> fb2=1.1 give the same result.

Comment: Ya It has two precision if it have values other than zero but I need a representation always with two precision like 1.20 not 1.2

Comment: @user3669712 from a float perspective, 1.20 and 1.2 are equal - you can always format it as a string with two decimals, but that's a different question.

Comment: @user3669712 `1.20` is a `String`, `1.2` might be a float. A float wont care for trailing zeros when you print it.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah@assylias Thank you for the comment.Now I m clear

Answer (score 0):

```
float fb2 = Float.parseFloat(fb + "." + fb1);
```

As simple as that ;)

Answer (score 0):

float fb2 = Float.parseFloat(Integer.toString(fb)+"."+ Integer.toString(fb1));

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
    int fb = (int) (duration.toMinutes() / 60.0);
    int fb1 = (int) (duration.toMinutes() % 60.0);

    float fb2 = java.lang.Float.valueOf(fb +"."+ fb1);
```

Comment: Btw, you don't need to do that `String` stuff on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods in Float wrapper class
1) parseFloat
2) valueOf

You can use any of this

```
float f=Float.parseFloat(fb+"."+fb1);
```

or

```
float f=Float.valueOf(fb+"."+fb1);
```